# Placing a $_SESSION into a mySQL query

Tags: php, sql, session

I have a query which runs fine if I manually declare **$add** to be a value (30 for example) by when I try to set it to the user_id session the query fails.

```
// $add = 30;
// The line above works
$add = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id']);
$query = "UPDATE mytable SET act=0, add=$add WHERE id=$selected_user";
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you have a value coming from session

Comment: Yes, I'm writing the session to the page fine

Comment: Have you verified the $_SESSION['user_id'] has a value?

Comment: What does $query look like after the assignment? Just echo or var_dump it.

Comment: Show your code where you're using the `$_SESSION` to set `$add`

Comment: `var_dump() $add` and `$query` and see what the output is.

Comment: How does the query fail, exactly? What's the error returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using sessions you always need to specify this before any `$_SESSION` usage like this:

```
session_start();
//now you are able to use this
$_SESSION['user_id'] = 30;
```

By the other hand, I got the same problem as you before and what you need to do is to
put the `$_SESSION['user_id']` in a variable, then you will be able to pass it to the `mysql_real_escape_string` without problems.

```
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
//now use this:
$add = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doh! Basic error by me (php newbie)... I forgot session_start() on the page running the query! Thanks

Comment: No problem, also try to do my second suggestion, I got some crashes before when passing $_SESSION directly too and don't forget to check my answer if resolves your problem :-)

Comment: Thanks... I am doing that, but wanted to avoid cluttering the question with unrelated code.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

A: Yes.  Session is empty.

SUGGESTIONS:

1. Do an "echo" to verify that $_SESSION['user_id'] is empty (I'm 99% sure it will be)
2. Make sure you're actually setting a session (e.g. "session_start()")
3. Make sure your "session_start()" occurs *before* your `<html>` tag.
4. Debug the code that sets  $_SESSION['user_id']

This is a good link:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Answer (score 0):

I can almost guarantee that you've forgotten `session_start();` at the top of your script. If not try echoing the session variable, if nothing is returned, you haven't set anything to it.